# Gracenote Mobile SDK MID-Stream returning incorrect results.

Tags: android, ios, gracenote

I have been trying very hard for the last 2 days to find out the reason but to no avail. 
Gracenote Mobile SDK MID-Stream is returning in correct results. MID-File is working fine.

At first, I thought may be something wrong with my application. However, tried with the sample applications hosted by Gracenote (both Android and iOS) on the following URL
developer.gracenote.com/mobile-client

Both, Android and iOS are returning incorrect results.

Also, tried with the MusixMatch App which is also using Gracenote itself and the results are incorrect.

This led to belief that there was some problem while ingesting the content itself. However, when i tried with MID-File Service, I am getting the correct results.

I have tested this with many tracks. Here is a list of few of them.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgX53MGraRc
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RvAKjau-C4

Lastly, SoundHound and Shazam are detecting them properly. 
Appreciate your help/ input in this regards.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Anurag

Comment: Do you know hot to upload new songs on gracenote using mobile sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this and for such a detailed report, we should have a fix live soon.

The discrepancy between MID-File and MID-Stream isn't too surprising as they actually query against different fingerprint databases - catered to the type of input audio (streaming audio from microphones vs decoded local audio).

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. By when do you think the fix should be up. 

One quick question. While going through the documentation, I came across the following

_When configured for a single best match, characteristics of all possible matches are compared against your application's specific criteria. To change the best match criteria, you can set configuration object properties._

Can you help with any specific property which would help change the results. I have tried with many permutations and combinations to no avail. 

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: sorry for the delayed reply, I want to make sure I didn't misspeak. we found the content issue in the streaming DB and are working to fix it ASAP. As far as configuring your queries for better matches, that is actually a 'bug' in the docs and due to some miscommunication between the engineers and the tech writers. the SDK automatically applies all of the 'best match criteria' that you provide as input. so, continue to give us all of the information you can, and we'll continue to try and give you the correct/best answer. When you find responses that are incorrect, please do report them to us!

Comment: (I've been told the fix is live, give it a whirl and let us know if you still see any issues)

Comment: Thanks. Gave it a preliminary test and still getting incorrect results. Will test it further and get back to you.

Comment: Hi! Testing it again and now it seems to be working properly. 
Just curious as if what could have caused the issue and if the fix took care of all the tracks across all the languages. Thanks again!

Comment: great, glad it is fixed! and yes, I believe the fix should be language independent.